How to automatically invert colors in .cal and .GP4 images files with Python?
I have several thousand plans in .cal and .GP4 whose colors I need to invert (switch to "positive" mode when they are in "negative"). I know it is possible to do it one by one in softwares like autocad but I am looking for a mass processing method for obvious reasons of saving time.
I created a Python program in order to perform the operation but a priori there are no libraries that allow to easily manipulate the .cal and .GP4 files. I also looked at a solution of parsing the .cal and .GP4 files to find the parameter to modify, but that did not give anything either.
Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

You could try doing one in AutoCAD by hand, and then compare the new file with the original with a hex editor to see if it's e.g. a single flag to flip, or if all the data gets changed...

The file conversion from .cal to .jpeg or other classic images extensions is cutting some important meta data like scale or filters for example.
I have found an option in Autodesk design review (a programm made to read cal and GP4 files) which allow to read directly the plans in negative mode. As this option is set once for a while i do not need to convert the images stock anymore.
For information this option is "file parameters", Format DWF : set to DWF files (.dwf) instead of default setting DWFx files (.dwfx).

These formats are going to be hard to read with a python library
But you could simply first convert those files to more common formats such as png using imagemagick

either directly from the commandline convert input_image.cal converted_image.png
Or in Python using Wand (the bindings to ImageMagick)


Then you can simply process the images with opencv. If you just want to set them in "negative", it would be as simple as
img = cv2.imread("converted_image.png")
if np.issubdtype(img.dtype, np.integer):
   img = img / 255.

negative_img = 1 - img

cv2.imwrite("negative_image.png", negative_img)


And finally convert back to the original format with imagemagick if needed

Looks like .cal files may contain multiple layers, pages, etc.; converting to PNG and back would be lossy.

according to this there are two type of CALS formats. Type 1 has only one image, so this should work fine on it. Type 2 is an archive, I'm not sure how imagemagick handles that, it might just output several pngs (like it would do if you used convert on a multi-page PDF)

Although with this method, some header information / metadata would still be lost. You would need a specialized library, or to make your own, in order to keep that
